# Logging to stderr in Console Scripts which use Django

Tags: django, logging, console-application

Configuring logging works fine for web requests.

But how do I configure the logging for console script which run are called from the unix shell or via cron?

For those scripts I want all logging to got to stderr.

I could not find how to solve this in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.py`

```
 'handlers': {
        'stream_to_console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myproject': {
            'handlers': ['stream_to_console'],
            'level' : 'DEBUG',
        },
```

In your `management/commands/my_command.py`

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('myproject')

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    ...

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        logger.warn("In management command")
```

And when you run `./manage.py my_command` it will output that warning to stderr